# fnmatch translate is escaping unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode

I am using following code

```
str = fnmatch.translate(u'ö')
print str
```

But it prints out as

```
'\ö'
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of [fnmatch.translate](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.translate) is to turn a shell pattern into a regular expression. Adding a backslash in front of non-ascii characters may not be as terse as possible, but it still works as a regular expression properly:

```
In [25]: re.match('\ö', u'ö')
Out[25]: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x92fef38>
```

The backslash has a special meaning only when it precedes certain characters (e.g. numbers, `A`, `b`, `B`, `d`, ...) If it precedes other characters, such as `'ö'`, the backslash is ignored.